# How to style TextViews that look like "cards"?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create an android style that allows me to put TextViews, pictures, and other elements within the "cards" as demonstrated in the link below. I think that design really adds depth and helps separate content from the background and I'd like to use it in my app. However, I don't know how to create that. If you could help that'd be greatly appreciated! :-)

[android card design example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy5GZ.png)

Comment: Like an xml file? If you want to create a layout that contains items, make the layout hierarchy in a .xml and then add views as necessary at run time. Or have a pre-defined layout with a pre-defined set of views and just set them at runtime. you can stack multiple .xml layouts in .xml layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those `TextView` just have a **custom background**. This may be

1. A 9-patch image
2. A xml-drawable

I suggest reading on [9-patch drawables](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) and on [android drawables in general](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html).

The reason why I think it's a 9-patch is that this "card" has a slight drop shadow.

Answer (score 0):

See if this Library helps you

http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/cardsui/